# Drupal 6 - Custom Node Type Template in Module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I have a module which adds a new content type.

For this content type I want to supply a node_contenttype.tpl.php node type template,
but Drupal will not recognize this template in the module directory, only in a theme.

How do I get Drupal (6) to use my template?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/6)

Here is an example of its use in a custom module that works for me (Just replace 'mymodule' with the name of your module):

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme_registry_alter()
 */
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $template = 'node';
  $originalpath = array_shift($theme_registry[$template]['theme paths']);
  $modulepath = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');
  // Stick the original path with the module path back on top
  array_unshift($theme_registry[$template]['theme paths'], $originalpath, $modulepath);
}
```

Now, Drupal will check your module folder for node template overrides.